# Is app created with WebApplicationFactory listening on real port on host machine?

Tags: .net-core

In tests I am using `WebApplicationFactory` and creating client with `WebApplicationFactory.CreateClient()`. The problem is that endpoint that I am testing sets some cookies which have to be sent to other service running on host machine on specific port (localhost:5555 for example). So my options are:

1. Somehow use this client to make request to localhost:5555 instead of tested WebApplication - but it seems client created this way always forwards any url to tested WebApplication.
2. If app created by WebApplicationFactory was bound to a real port on host machine then I could just use custom http client and make requests to both ports (to tested application port and 5555). But I am not sure if WebApplicationFactory exposes application on real port and how to configure this port. I tried to configure port with standard Kestrel settings, but it seems either WebApplicationFactory ignores the config or it does not bind to any real port.

Answer (score 0):

The general `_fixture` uses the `applicationUrl` from the `launchSettings.json` normally `5001` and `5000` and that is fine when all the tests use the same `builder.Services` and `Builder.Configuration` set in `Program.cs`. But when it's not, like for example the ef core database context should be isolated per test because you don't want tests to share the same cached datastore, you need to run every test on a different port. If you don't the parallel processing will lead to the following exception:

```bash
  Error Message:
   System.IO.IOException : Failed to bind to address http://127.0.0.1:5000: address already in use.
```

You can change the port per test into something unique:

```cs
public class WhenTestingPluginImport : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory>
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _fixture;

    public WhenTestingPluginImport(CustomWebApplicationFactory fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void ImportGraphDataTest()
    {
        var fixture = _fixture.WithWebHostBuilder(builder => 
            builder.UseUrls($"http://*:8501/"));
        using var scope = fixture.Services.CreateScope();
        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var context = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<DomainContext>();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        var request = new PluginImportRequest { Plugin = Domain.GraphPlugin };
        var handler = new PluginImportHandler(context);
        await handler.Handle(request, new CancellationToken());
        context.Workspaces.Count().Should().Be(1);
        context.Logins.Count().Should().Be(3);
        context.Blocks.Count().Should().Be(25);
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async void ImportAccessDataTest()
    {
        var fixture = _fixture.WithWebHostBuilder(builder => 
            builder.UseUrls($"http://*:8502/"));
        using var scope = fixture.Services.CreateScope();
        var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var context = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<DomainContext>();
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        var request = new PluginImportRequest { Plugin = Domain.AccessPlugin };
        var handler = new PluginImportHandler(context);
        await handler.Handle(request, new CancellationToken());
        context.Workspaces.Count().Should().Be(1);
        context.Logins.Count().Should().Be(8);
        context.Blocks.Count().Should().Be(49);
        context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }
}
```